# SVG line over draggable divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am trying to draw a line that will connect some point to any `draggable` div.
The dynamic computation of positions seem to be ok, but, as the div is being dragged, the line disappears behind some elements at some moments.
Moreover, `div`s from the first range cannot be dragged when handled at the top. I guess this second problem has the same origin as the first one.

Here is my code **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yannn/dh9oha6h/3/)**

The div that contains SVG follows the draggable divs:

```
<div class="svgbox">
    <svg  width="100%" height="100%">
        <line id="idline" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0" stroke="red"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Here is the `CSS` for this div:

```
.svgbox {
 position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Yann

Comment: Thumbs up for including a JSFiddle, but you should also include segments of relevant code here, in case the JSFiddle goes away for whatever reason. =]

Comment: Ok, i guess the two code snippets i embedded were not comprehensive enough.

Comment: The [SO how to ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) says that using jsfiddle is great, but not everyone can access external sites, and links may break over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
.svgbox {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index: 10;    /* this, to make it always on-top and */
    pointer-events: none; /* this, to passtrough pointer events to underlying elements */
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dh9oha6h/4/)

Comment: oh, magic ! I will do some more tests later, but thanks a lot, Roko.

Comment: Below a certain level, the line disappeared. I added `width: 100%;
    height: 100%;` and it seems to be fixed.